# Fedora failing to install on VirtualBox in Mac OSX

Tags: mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora

I'm trying to install Fedora on VirtualBox on my MacBook. I set up a VDI drive from the selection list and allocated 20gb hard drive space and 4gb of ram. Boot up the machine and load from the Fedora ISO image and go through the installation process. The installation finished and required a reboot so I selected reset from the VirtualBox menu, and when it boots back it leads me to the same menu I started with (`Try Fedora` and `Install to Disk`).

I've tried installing it multiple times, powering off the machine then booting it back and I get the same result. I'm driving and not at my computer now, but I think powering off the machine and 'saving current state' might do the trick. Can anyone confirm or state another solution?

Comment: did you change the boot order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In machine window: choose **Devices** from menu -> **Optical Drives** -> **Remove disk from virtual drive**

Then reboot the virtual machine.

(Alternatively you can go to machine settings in main VirtualBox window, select Storage tab, highlight the optical drive, click on a small disk icon, then choose to remove)